# iisreset command works only in alternate executions

Tags: iis

I open the terminal in Administrator mode.
The `iisreset` command in the first run, gives the message:

> Attempting stop... Restart attempt failed. Access denied, you must be
> an administrator of the remote computer to use this command. Either
> have your account added to the administrator local group of the remote
> computer or to the domain administrator global group.

When I execute again it works. I keep the terminal open.
In the 3rd run it fails but in the 4th it works.

[image]

Comment: so IIS has an annoying idiosyncracy... after stopping the parent process, all the application pool processes must also complete shutdown, before the services can be restarted. if the processes have a lot of ram in their footprint, it takes a few seconds. I usually stop an app pool, and then count slowly to 5 before attempting to restart it. that works most of the time...

Comment: @FrankThomas The time between my each command execution is more than 10 seconds. Are you suggesting that I stop app pool instead of `iisreset`.

Comment: no, I'm just saying that IIS often takes longer to die than expected, so tooling that expects a timely turnaround will experience this kind of error. you could try the /timeout:nn switch to see if that helps

Comment: A heads-up that you had this tagged [tag:windows-terminal], but the screenshot you provided specifically shows that you *aren't* using Windows Terminal.  Instead, you are using Windows Console Host, a different application.  I've removed the tag and replaced it with [tag:command-line], which is what I think you meant.  Thanks!